# How to call AssumeRoleWithSAMLAsync without AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am calling AssumeRoleWithSAMLAsync using AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient, while creating the client object it is mandatory to configure a credentials where as my intention is to create temporary credentials using AssumeRoleWithSaml.

The documentation of AWS STS service says that AssumeRoleWithSaml doesn't require credentials but client constructor requires credentials.

I also tried calling api directly with following parameters

`https://sts.amazonaws.com/ ?Version=2011-06-15&Action=AssumeRoleWithSAML&RoleArn=arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx&DurationSeconds=900&PrincipalArn=arn:aws:iam::xxx:saml-provider/adfs&SAMLAssertion=base64 ecoded SAML token`

But this also throws error

`<Code>InvalidIdentityToken</Code>
        <Message>Invalid base64 SAMLResponse (Service: AWSOpenIdDiscoveryService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthSamlInvalidSamlResponseException; Request ID: xx-xxxx-xxx)</Message>`

When I configure credentials, I am able to create temporary credentials. Hence I am sure my SAML token is correct.

Can anyone let me know how to call AssumeRoleWithSAML from postman? or how can I call it via code without instantiating client?

It seems to me a chicken and egg problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AnonymousAWSCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TRuntimeAnonymousAWSCredentials.html) class to create credentials that can be used by the client while exchanging the SAML token for your temporary role credentials.